# can I charge New MacBook Pro 2016 with use Apple iPad 12W USB Power Adapter since they are all usb c?

Tags: laptop, usb

Any potential problem with charge New MacBook Pro 2016 with use Apple iPad 12W USB Power Adapter since they are all usb c?

Comment: hardware recomendations... isn't it suppose to recommend hardware? maybe this space should be renamed